# mv and cp with automatic diff

Tags: cp, mv, diff

Is there a program out there like mv and cp, which upon conflict automatically shows a diff before asking whether to override the target file?

This is such a basic feature in graphical file managers,
and I am missing it on the Terminal.

Comment: I'm questioning whether showing a diff of files that contains "conflicts" is a standard feature of file managers. What constitutes a "conflict"? What is supposed to be shown if the files are not text files?  The standard `cp` and `mv` utilities are not generic version control tools.

Comment: Don't know if "diffing" is actually a standard feature of GUI file managers, but showing a dialog comparing size and age of the files most definitely is; and I'd agree with xeruf, an interactive command line tool doing that is kind of missing, beyond what `cp -i` can do.

Comment: "_shows a diff_" - of content or metadata (timestamp, for example)?

Comment: I think with the term "diff" he meant of file size, attributes and modification date, and I kinda agree with that. I use linux for ages and never thought of it. I think I will write a little script for this. If so I will post it here as answer :)

Comment: really I don't care what is diffed, I just want some info, and if they are same in metadata and content don't even bother me about it